# Inequality involving homogenous function of degree -1

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, integral-inequality

> Let $p\in[1,\infty]$. For $f\in L^p(0,\infty)$ we define $Tf:x\mapsto \int_0^\infty K(x,y)f(y)\,dy$ where $K$ is homogenous of degree $-1$, i.e. $K(\lambda x,\lambda y) = \lambda^{-1} K(x,y)$ for $\lambda>0$. Suppose that $$A_K=\int_0^\infty |K(1,y)|y^{-1/p}\,dy<\infty.$$
>
> Then $\|Tf\|_p\leq A_K\|f\|_p$.

My attempts included applying the generalised Minkowski-inequality and dualizing $L^p=(L^q)^*$ but the farthest I've gotten is showing that $$\|Tf\|_p\leq \int_0^\infty |f(y)|\left( \int_0^\infty |K(x,y)|^pdx\right)^{1/p}dy$$
but it doesn't exactly seem promising.

I'm extremely thankful for any help!

Comment: Have you tried using $K(x,y) = x^{-1}\cdot K(1,y/x)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I don't immediately see how to use that fact.

Comment: I don't either, but it looks like it might be useful, so I asked whether you already tried it.

Comment: @iwriteonbananas for $p = \infty$, do we interpret $A_K$ as $\int_0^\infty |K(1,y)|\, dy$?

Comment: @kobe Yes, that's right.